# How do I change the name of the python DLL when compiling a library like pillow?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, dll

**Question:**
I want to compile a third-party library like Pillow or Numbpy but I want to change the name of the python27.dll to corepython27.dll.  How do I do this during the compile process?  Is it something I need to change in the setup.py?  Or the distutils library?

I should explain that I have no experience in compiling at all.  I just know that I will need to make this change as I learn more about the basics of compiling.

**Explanation:**
Corel's PaintShop Pro uses an embedded python interpreter to run scripts inside the program.  And I would like to be able to use third-party libraries like pillow and numpy but they always fail to load.  The version of python that is included with PaintShop Pro is 2.7.5.  I've made sure to download the appropriate versions of these libraries but it always fails with a "DLL module doesn't exist" type error.

Using a PE viewer I was able to see that other libraries like TKinter were using imports corepython27.dll instead of python27.dll like pillow was.

Also pillow for 2.7 was using msvcr90.dll but the custom version of the tkinter library included with PSP was compiled with msvcr110.dll.  Do you think this will be an issue?  Do I need to compile pillow with the appropriate version of msvcr DLL?  Or is matching versions (2.7) and making sure it uses the correct python.dll (corepython27.dll) the only important thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a symbolic link named corepython27.dll showing to the installed python27.dll. You can do this in your console via the command

```
MKLINK <path_to_corepython.dll> <path_to_python27.dll>
```

Comment: Thank you, I would never have thought of that.  I'm still curious about compiling but this is definitely the simplest option available.  :D  It appears to be working like a charm, which also answers my question on whether the msvcr.dlls need to match.